# Where to save something between invocations?

Tags: python

The 2nd time I run this program I'd like it to start in the same HDD location as the previous instance. How should I save, or remember, where I was so the program starts in the same place?

I'd like to persist my previous location the same way across MAC, Linux, Windows, ...

Where is a good place to save my location so it's available to me the next time I run?

Comment: Do you mean file system location(working directory) or program execution state?

Comment: File system location (working directory). But the same thing applies to other types of data too, though less frequently. I'd like the program to remember what values this user had set and restore those values.

Comment: I'd say [How do I store desktop application data in a cross platform way for python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1084697) is relevant here. What remains then is a choice of file format; JSON, shelve, pickle are all options depending on your usecases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best place to store those things is in a file below the users home directory.

> I'd like to persist my previous location the same way across MAC, Linux, Windows

The conventions how to find the users home directory are different at different operating systems, also the conventions how programs have to use the folder hierarchy below there. At least, there is always an environment variable available which can be checked for getting the home directory root (`%UserProfile%` for Windows, `$HOME` for Linux/Unix/Mac). See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory for a list.

[This former SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/what-is-a-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-home-directory) tells you how to determine the home directory when using Python in a platform-independend way.

For Windows, here is some more detailed information where exactly to store application files:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/patricka/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions)

For Unix/Linux, look into the filesystem hierarchy standard:

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#HOMEUSERHOMEDIRECTORIES

Comment: This is a good answer to "Save the data where?" but doesn't touch on format. Can you say a little bit about what format you would keep the data?

Comment: @DaleE.Moore: choosing a file format for persistence is a topic on its own, very opinionated and thus IMHO not suitable for this site. So best advice I can give you is the same as in the comment from Martijn Pieters.